# C# version of jquery.md5.js

Tags: c#, jquery

I try to convert the awesome script jquery.md5.js to C# for my own purpose.
But I can't figure it out these two methods:

```
function rstr2binl(input) {
    var i,
        output = [];
    output[(input.length >> 2) - 1] = undefined;
    for (i = 0; i < output.length; i += 1) {
        output[i] = 0;
    }
    for (i = 0; i < input.length * 8; i += 8) {
        output[i >> 5] |= (input.charCodeAt(i / 8) & 0xFF) << (i % 32);
    }
    return output;
}
```

I don't understand very well what is he doing with "output"...

```
function rstr_hmac_md5(key, data) {
    var i,
        bkey = rstr2binl(key),
        ipad = [],
        opad = [],
        hash;
    ipad[15] = opad[15] = undefined;                        
    if (bkey.length > 16) {
        bkey = binl_md5(bkey, key.length * 8);
    }
    for (i = 0; i < 16; i += 1) {
        ipad[i] = bkey[i] ^ 0x36363636;
        opad[i] = bkey[i] ^ 0x5C5C5C5C;
    }
    hash = binl_md5(ipad.concat(rstr2binl(data)), 512 + data.length * 8);
    return binl2rstr(binl_md5(opad.concat(hash), 512 + 128));
}

"ipad[15] = opad[15] = undefined;"
```

I can't do that in C#...

Thanks beforehand!

P.S.: Strange behavior, I can't say Hello, its always deleted...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I won't translate all code to C#, but explain a few points:

```
var output = [];
output[(input.length >> 2) - 1] = undefined;
```

This is *one way* to set the array length in javascript. Basically you say thet elements `[0 ... (input.length >> 2) - 1]` are `undefined` - which can be compared to `null` in C#. As you are calculating some values I would avoid nullable types and simply initialize the array to `0` - So the C# equivalent would be:

```
int[] output = new int[(input.Length >> 2)];
```

The next thing is that instead of normal division right bit shifts are used. If you compare [the C#](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xt18et0d.aspx) and [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Right_shift) descriptions of the operators, you'll see they're doing the same thing. Therefore, no conversion is required but you could simply write `new int[input.Length / 4]`.

Please note that in the [current version](http://pajhome.org.uk/crypt/md5/md5.html) of the script the array initialization is done like this:

```
var output = Array(input.length >> 2);
```

And as a final note: unless you are doing this for self-education, **take an existing C# MD5 implementation**, there should be plenty avaliable. This will help you to avoid errors and performance issues.

Comment: Thank you very much! That help me a lot!